# Yeoman angularjs-cordova app - как же с этим всем работать?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

Я собрал апликацию по этому руководству: https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angularjs-cordova с помощью `yeoman` и `angularjs-cordova generator`.
Во время установки, появилось приглашение для выбора плагинов кардовы и я выбрал `cordova.device`, `cordova.camera` и `cordova.vibration`.
После этого я запустил апликацию в браузере с помощью `grunt serve`.
Все выглядит ок.
После этого я пропробовал в `applicaton.js` (`app\js\application.js`) получить информацию про устройство (плагин `cordova.device`), но переменная `device` не определена.
В консоли firebug'а я увидел следующие ошибки:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://127.0.0.1:9000/cordova.js"  
"ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"
```

Я не понимаю, почему cordova.js и jquery не подключились автоматом и вообще, где и как их подключать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается решение намного проще чем я думал!
Переменная device появляется только на устройсте или эмуляторе.
В веб браузере ее нет!
Тоесть когда я запустил апликацию на симуляторе андроида - все заработало!

> Только надо помнить, что файлы из папки app должны быть скопированы в папку www